# Why do we take the derivative as zero in this question?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Today, I was solving this [KVPY-SA 2017 Question](http://kvpy.iisc.ernet.in/main/resources/2017/SA_05-NOV-17.pdf):

> 62. In an isosceles trapezium, the length of one of the parallel sides, and the lengths of the non-parallel sides are all equal to $30$. In order to maximize the area of the trapezium, the
>     smallest angle should be:
>     A) $π/6$
>     B) $π/4$
>     C) $π/3$
>     D) $π/2$

So, I took the angle as $θ$ and after that I found the *Area* by using the $sin$ and $cos$ functions like this:
$$A=900\sin\theta(\cos\theta + 1)$$

And after that I found the derivative of area like this:
$$\begin{align*}\frac{dA}{d\theta} &= \frac{d}{d\theta}[900(\sin\theta)(1+\cos\theta)]\\
&= 900\left[(\sin\theta)\frac{d}{d\theta}(1+\cos\theta)+(1+\cos\theta)\frac{d}{d\theta}(\sin\theta)\right]\end{align*}$$

And after many steps I reached here where I put the derivative as equal to $0$:
$$\frac{dA}{d\theta} =900[\sin\theta\cdot(-\sin\theta)+(1+\cos\theta)\cdot(\cos\theta)]=0$$

I don't know why I should put it equal to $0$ but that's how you find the answer. When I searched for answers on google I found [this solved paper](https://byjus.com/jee/kvpy-sa-2017-maths-question-paper/) by Byju's. In their answer, you would see that they've written:

> Differentiating both sides with respect to $\theta$,
> $$\frac{dA}{d\theta} = 900[{\sin\theta\cdot(–\sin \theta) +(1 + \cos\theta)\cdot\cos\theta }] = 0\text{ (for critical points)}$$

What did they mean by differentiation = $0$ for critical points?
You know, I'm very bad at calculus so please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

Edit:
What I did after putting the derivative=$0$ :-
$$-sin²\theta+cos\theta+cos²\theta=0$$
$$⇒cos²\theta-1+cos\theta+cos ²\theta=0$$
$$⇒2cos²\theta+cos\theta-1=0$$
$$⇒2cos²\theta+2cos\theta-cos\theta-1=0$$
$$⇒2cos\theta(cos\theta+1)-1(cos\theta+1)=0$$
$$⇒(2cos\theta-1)(cos\theta+1)=0$$

Comment: The maximum or minimum of a differentiable function can be attained only at points where the derivative is zero. A "critical point" is a point where the derivative is zero, and the idea is that if you find such a point, the second derivative's sign can be used to check if the point is a minimum or maximum.

Comment: Basically it's about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)

So the lesson of the day for you is: "If I want to find the maxima or minima of a function, I need to look at where the **derivative** is zero." It might sound weird, but it's simply the truth. And once you think about it, it can even make sense.

Comment: The derivative defines the slope of the tangent line to a function at a point. A zero derivative means that the tangent line is horizontal. This will be the case at humps in the graph of the function. These points are therefore candidates for local minima and maxima.

Comment: Look, I've studied that _"the derivative is the **instantaneous rate of change** of $y$ with respect to $x$"_. So, if the derivative is zero here, doesn't it mean that the rate of change of Area with respect to $θ$(angle of the trapezium) is equal to zero? That's really confusing me!!

Comment: That's right.  If the derivative were positive, then increasing the angle slightly would make the area larger;  if the derivative were negative, then decreasing the angle slightly would make the area larger.  So the only way to have the "largest" area is with derivative zero.

Comment: Aren't there two possible solutions depending on $a$ is the shorter or the longer parallel side?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, No. There's only solution for area. The formula for area of a trapezium is:$$A=(h/2)(a+b)$$ So it doesn't matter if you interchange 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon, I found out these two:$$(2cos\theta-1)=0$$ and $$(cos\theta+1)=0$$Now, how do I know whether the point is maximum or minimum?

Comment: Use the second derivative : find the solutions to these equations, and plug them in the second derivative. If the sign is positive, then that point is a minimum. If the sign is negative, that point is a maximum.

Comment: @John Douma, see my edits. I've simplified it now h do I know whether they're the maximum or the minimum. You said that if the derivative is equal to zero, it can mean both maximum and minimum. So which is which?

Comment: @lee It may be neither. You can use the second derivative test. Setting the derivative to zero eliminates candidates, it doesn't tell you whether you have a minimum or maximum. Consider $f(x)=x^3$ at $x=0$. The derivative is zero but $f(0)$ is neither a local minimum or a local maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a function is continuous on a closed interval a maximum either is interior (0 first derivative, negative second derivative) or must lie on the boundary of the domain.

We need to compare the value of the local maximum and the values on the boundaries of the domain.

A local maximum has 0 first derivative because intuitively the next point in infinitessimal difference will not be any different.

A local maximum has negative second derivative because intuitively the next point will have a negative first derivative (the second next point will attain even less)

Comment: Your answer is a little complicated. Could you please explain with simple terms? And, with respect to my question?

Comment: @lee We want to maximize the Area of the Trapezium and $900\sin\theta(\cos\theta + 1)$ is the function which gives us the Area of the Trapezium with respect to $\theta$. So we differentiate $900\sin\theta(\cos\theta + 1)$ with respect to $\theta$ set the derivative to 0, check if the derivative is negative at the  $\theta$ that supposedly maximazes the Area